# disable Anonymous Authentication for a web Application hosted in Azure VM

Tags: azure, authentication, anonymous

I have implemented azure keyvault in my application and when I disable the Anonymous authentication and Enable te windows authentication in IIS I get the following error.

---

> Server Error in '/' Application. Keyset does not exist Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.  Exception Details:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not
>   exist Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

---

Please help me to solve this.I am trying this in IIS express and published my application as a new website in IIS.

Comment: Please don't attach images of code or error messages, copy-paste them into your question body instead.

Comment: it did not allow me to paste it in my question body.

Comment: The error does not look related to authentication, you are trying to get an access token for some API from Azure AD with a certificate instead of a secret, but it is failing to validate something on that.

Comment: Ya i am using a certificate instead of secret, because of fortify scan .